# Validate whether a double/decimal is currency C#

Tags: c#

I am reading in a pipe delimited file and need to check whether a column is a valid currency (i.e. it must follow a format as xxxxx.xx , so a maximum of two digits after the decimal although it is not necessary to have any digits after the decimal).  How would I go about doing this in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try converting your value to a currency, like this:

```
double dummy;
bool valid = double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out dummy);
```

`valid` will then be either true if TryParse could parse it as a currency. This is by far a better option than using regular expressions.

To get the fraction (decimals) of your value, just convert it to an int and subtract it from the original value, like:

```
double fraction = value - (int)value;
```

`fraction` will then contain decimals and you can do whatever you like with them.

Comment: This would require the format being $10.00 rather than 10.00 tho wouldn't it? 10.00 would fail to parse since it's not formatted as currency.

Comment: *tests it* Ok you're right, but yeah fails on decimal places requirement. Thanks for teaching me something new tho!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

if (Regex.IsMatch(myString, @"\d+(\.\d{1,2})?"))
{
    // ...
}
```

or use [decimal.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) if you just want to check that you can convert it to a decimal:

```
decimal value;
if (decimal.TryParse(myString, out value))
{
    // Do something with value
}
```

Comment: This means that 1.1 is a valid value. Whether that's right or not is not clear from the question.

Comment: The moment he converts 1.10 to a decimal or double it's going to be 1.1 anyway. I think if he REQUIRES to check for only 2 decimal places he should use a regex for that, prior to it being converted.

Comment: Sorry - I fixed the question.  There does not necessarily need to be any digits after the decimal if the decimal exists.

Comment: It would be strange to validate "1.".  However if you want to do so you could use this regular expression: `@"\d+(\.\d*)?"`

Answer (score 0):

looks a bit hacky, but interesting way to ensure that you've parsed money correct:

float amount = float.TryParse("$1,200,000.34", NumberStyles.Currency);

bool fractionLooksFine = (new System.Version((amount*100).ToString()).Minor == 0);